# Parsing Data from a Website in Objective-c

Tags: objective-c, xml-parsing, html-parsing

Can you create an XML for a website that you do not own?

This is the first question came to my mind when I was thinking to do the following demo app:

Let's say there is a `Main Page` contains `5 Best Students` each has a unique URL with the pattern (`http://www.URL.com/StudentDetail.aspx?Id=xxx`) directing to a `Student Detail Page`.

In `Student Detail Page` there are 3 attributes for a Student. `(Name,GPA,Major)`

The website updates the names every day with new `5 Students` and different `5 URLS` with the pattern I mentioned above.

[image]

So, If I want to parse all the 5 best students to my UIView. What would be the best ideal way to do it? HTML Parsing would be a nightmare for me because the html `Main Page` code is not well organized. That's why I asked the first question above.

Answer (score 0):

Though some say that you can't use regex for parsing HTML pages here I'd still recommend to try it. If you need to simply extract strings matching your pttern (like http://www.URL.com/StudentDetail.aspx?Id=xxx) regex may come to the rescue. And you don't need to worry about bad HTML.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up! I do have an idea but I don't think it's convenient. I hope more SOF masters give me some idea or advise to more forward.

Comment: Personally, I used regex in scraping many times. In some cases it's quite convenient ))